# do not return the widget that has an empty container flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a method that returns a list of widgets. each widget has a futurebuilder. if there is no data it returns an empty container. I don't want to return widgets that have an empty container in the method.

```
 List<Widget> _widgetList() {
    List<Widget> list = [
      widget1(),
       widget2(),
    ];

    return list;
  }
```

wiget1 and widget2 are both the same

````
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Mydata?>(
      future: fetchdatas(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active ) {
          return loading();
        }
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
         return Stack(
            children: [
              widcard (
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8))
                      ),
                   
                       Text(snapshot.data!.fistarticle),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          );
        } else {
          return container();
        }
      },
    );
  }```
````

Comment: `      future: fetchdatas(),` is broken. Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: I have a method that returns a list of widgets. each widget has a futurebuilder. if there is no data it returns an empty container. I don't want to return widgets that have an empty container in the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Widget>? widget1() {
//Your function 
  return null; // return List<Widget>?;
}

List<Widget> _widgetList() {
  List<Widget> list = [];
  List<Widget>? listWidget1 = widget1();
    List<Widget>? listWidget2 = widget2();

  if (listWidget1 != null) {
    list.addAll(listWidget1);
  }
  if (listWidget2 != null) {
    list.addAll(listWidget2);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this function  List<Widget> ? widget1() can you be more clear   widget1 is a statefull widget

Comment: show me your code, i need clearly to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I added the code of widget1 and 2 I want the function not to return the widget which has no data in futurebuilder